# Tab completion for alias with the same names in zsh

Tags: zsh, alias, tab-completion

I am using zsh.

I have a command `foo`, and I use `alias foo="sudo foo"` as a shortcut. I want zsh to complete the command just like I typed `foo`.

I googled and found `compdef _foo f=foo` which can deal with it. When I type `f something<tab>`, the completion works fine. But when I try `compdef _foo foo=foo` and then `foo something<tab>`, it does not work.

Is there a way to deal with the Tab completion when I use an alias with the same name as the original command?

Comment: look at `setopt complete_aliases` and try to set it or unset it depending on your current state. I also have aliases masking original commands and autocomplete for them is working fine.

Comment: You are over complicating. You do not need 'compdef'.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! I found it a mistake of mine that made things worse. I will explain it in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually a special case happened to me.

As @blueray said, zsh is able to complete commands like `sudo foo` or an alias of it normally.

Thanks to @rcwnd_cz , I found that adding `setopt complete_aliases` solves my problem. The point is that I set an alias somewhere else that maps `sudo` to `sudo FOO=bar`. As a result, `alias foo="sudo foo"` is an "alias in alias", and zsh refuses to complete it. Setting `setopt complete_aliases` solves it perfectly.